# Windows - thread id change when a context switch happens

Tags: windows, multithreading, native, multicore, context-switch

Do Thread Id's change when a context switch (due to any reason) happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx:

*GetCurrentThreadId()*

*Until the thread terminates, the thread identifier uniquely identifies the thread throughout the system.*

Answer (score 2):

The thread ID of a thread cannot change. A thread's ID remains constant through the thread's lifetime.